# How to keep a Keras model loaded into memory and use it when needed?

Tags: python, node.js, keras

I was reading a [Keras blog](https://blog.keras.io/building-a-simple-keras-deep-learning-rest-api.html) teaching how to create a simple image classifier restful API with Flask. I was wondering how to achieve the same approach of loading model in other web frameworks that do not use python.
In the code below the model is loaded into memory just before the server starts and it runs until the server is alive:

```
# if this is the main thread of execution first load the model and
# then start the server
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(("* Loading Keras model and Flask starting server..."
        "please wait until server has fully started"))
    load_model()
    app.run()
```

I'm familiar with [Pickle](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html) and I know how to run python code in other web frameworks (such as [python-shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell) of Node.js). pickled models are built once and can be loaded each time they're needed. but I'm looking to achieve the same thing as the tutorial suggests which is loading it only once, and using it multiple times. Is creating a separate python server app that serves the loaded model to Node.js requests a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can load a model in Keras using `load_model` and pass in a path:

```
from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model('model.hd5')
```

I have created a Flask API that loads a Keras model, you can take a look here if it helps:
https://github.com/Ares513/DetectingTrollsApi/blob/master/api.py

Comment: This is kinda the same as loading models via pickle. it is kept into memory until the script is run. so I need to load the model every time I want to classify image passed to the API. please note that I'm trying to keep the model in memory (python coed) while using it from another script (e.g. javascript). I know there can be a python server app that listens to this kind of calls which totally solves the problem. I was just wondering if there is another way to it. Thank you anyways.

Comment: Yes, the model that I load for my project (in Git) is loaded when the application starts and remains in memory until the worker restarts.

Comment: Hi Ares, I was writing an API using Keras model. It works fine on my laptop. But, It showing out of memory on my little server. Is there any method/code to check how much memory a model will take? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to develop a python "model" server in which the ML model is loaded into memory and is shared through sockets. the consumer app, on the other hand, is a simple Node.js web app that forwards the requests to the python server and retrieves the reply.
you can find the code sample here: [Keras deep api](https://github.com/khnshn/keras-deep-api)
this is an image classifier app that uses [ResNet50](https://keras.io/api/applications/resnet/#resnet50-function) to classify images. images can be uploaded through the Node.js app and are then passed to the python server for classification, the result is then sent back to the Node.js app.